# Angularjs - How to loop through a list of dictionaries in select optgroup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of categories, each one contains a sub categories under it. I am trying to fetch them inside a select options optgroup, here is how the list looks like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "First Category", 
      "0": {
        "name": "Sub 1", 
        "under": [
          "Under 1", 
          "Under 2"
        ]
      }, 
      "1": {
        "name": "Sub 2", 
        "under": [
          "Under 1", 
          "Under 2", 
          "Under 3"
        ]
      }, 
      "2": {
        "name": "Sub 3", 
        "under": [
          "Under 1", 
          "Under 2"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "category": "Second Category", 
      "0": {
        "name": "Sub 1", 
        "under": [
          "Under 1", 
          "Under 2"
        ]
      }, 
    },
  ]
}
```

I have another select that contains all categories. The second one shows up depending on my first selection, so for example, if I choose **First Category** all the subs and under sub should be appended inside the second selections:

```
// Fetch all available categories
$scope.initCategories = function(obj){
    $scope.promise = sendRequest.sendObject('/fetch-categories', obj, config)
    $scope.promise.then(function(success) {
        $scope.categories = success.data
        $scope.stepData.category = $scope.categories
        return true
    }, function(err) {
        return false, err
    })
}

<select class="form-control custom-select" name="categories" ng-model="stepData.category" ng-options="x.category for x in categories track by x.category">
</select>

<select ng-if="stepData.category" class="form-control custom-select" ng-model="stepData.sub" ng-options="sub group by sub.name for (index, key) in stepData.category[index]"></select>
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/182/

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, i've used `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options` in the second selection:

```
<select ng-if="category" id="product_sub_category" name="product_sub_category" class="form-control custom-select" ng-model="sub_category" ng-change="setSubCategory()">
    <optgroup ng-repeat="(index, key) in category track by $index" label="<%key.name%>">
        <option ng-repeat="value in key.under track by $index">
            <%value%>
        </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```